# Multiple left/right panels (SWRevealViewController)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

I am using SWRevealViewController to create sliding panels (like the Facebook app). I use segue identifiers sw_rear and sw_right. However, I can only have one of both it seems.

How do I create multiple panels?

I am using this tutorial: http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-sidebar-navigation-menu/

This is my code to setup the left and right panels in my ViewControllers:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Set the side bar button action. When it's tapped, it'll show up the sidebar.
    _leftSidebarButton.target = self.revealViewController;
    _leftSidebarButton.action = @selector(revealToggle:);

    // Set the side bar button action. When it's tapped, it'll show up the sidebar.
    _rightSidebarButton.target = self.revealViewController;
    _rightSidebarButton.action = @selector(rightRevealToggle:);

    // Set the pan gesture recognizer
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer];

    // Set the tap gesture recognizer
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.revealViewController.tapGestureRecognizer];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this simple library 
https://github.com/arturdev/AMSlideMenu 
In demo project you can see how to implement multiple menus in one app.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add the following line after you SWRevealViewController definition in delegate file

```
    RightViewController *rightViewController = (RightViewController *)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"RightViewController"];
```

Obviously you need your UI RightViewController in your storyboard with the correct identifier
Your code should seems like that:

```
    UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];
    SWRevealViewController *mainViewController = (SWRevealViewController *)[mainStoryboard
                                                                            instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainViewController"];

    RightViewController *rightViewController = (RightViewController *)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"RightViewController"];


    mainViewController.rightViewController = rightViewController;

    self.window.rootViewController = mainViewController;
    return YES;
```

I hope that helps you

Answer (score 0):

Just had this problem as well. If you're using storyboards, make sure the SWRevealViewController sets a segue **to** the VC to appear on the right, and **not the other way around**.